# How to access class properties using interface object which are not defined in the interface?

Tags: interface, decorator, factory

I am new to this forum. Now-days I am studying design patterns. I learnt about factory pattern and implemented simple example as shown below.

```
public interface IPlc
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    void Testping();
}
Public AbbPlc : IPlc
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string slotnumber { get; set; }// Property relevant with this class
    public void Testping()
    {
        console.writeline("ping executed successfully");
    }
}
Public SiemensPlc : IPlc
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string Racknumber { get; set; }// Property relevant with this class
    public void Testping()
    {
        console.writeline("ping executed successfully");
    }
}

//In Main Program

var objAbb = new IPlc() //Created object from interface
objAbb.Name = "46IC-PLC"; //Works OK
objAbb.slotnumber "3"; //Not works

var objSiemens = new IPlc() //Created object from interface

objSiemens.Name = "45IC-PLC"; //Works OK
objSiemens.Racknumber "5"; //Not works
```

Could you please tell me why these two methods doesn't work?
What I have to do to access properties from Interface object?
Do I need to use one more pattern with factory like decorator?

Comment: Type casting is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Tripp